# What to do with MFCC?

Tags: python, machine-learning, signal-processing, mfcc

I'm currently trying to implement a simple word recognization from a standard microphone with Python. I already sampled data and extract MFCC matrix from the audio signal. But the question is : What should I do with these features to get phonems or recognize a word ? 
NB: The words which I would to recognize represent a Proper Name of person.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post some code at which you are stuck. Also, list packages you're using.

Comment: did you make any progress? on what to do with mfcc?